# reset settings of one component from another

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-hooks

I have a screen where I am using some text and another component called FilterCriteriaList which has some custom buttons that change their color when we click on them.

On my main screen, I want to press on the text and reset the settings in the FilterCriteriaList component. This could be done by setting all `options[index].checked` to `false`. However, I cannot figure out how to do so such that we can select the buttons again as well.

```
type FilterCriteriaListProps = {
  deleteAll: boolean;
};

type CriteriaList = {
  title: string;
  checked: boolean;
};
const criteriaList = [
  { title: 'Nur Frauen', checked: false },
  { title: 'Freunde Zweiten Grades', checked: false },
  { title: 'Nichtraucherfahrzeug', checked: false },
  { title: 'Mit min. 4 Sternen bewertet', checked: false },
  { title: 'Automatische Zusage', checked: false },
];

export const FilterCriteriaList: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(criteriaList);

  const handleChange = (index: number) => {
    const options = [...selected];
    options[index].checked = options[index].checked ? false : true;
    setSelected(options);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
      {criteriaList.map((item: CriteriaList, index: number) => (
        <View key={index}>
          <View style={styles.criteriaRow}>
            <Icon
              name={item.checked ? 'dot-circle-o' : 'circle-thin'}
              color="#31C283"
              size={moderateScale(20)}
              onPress={() => handleChange(index)}
            />
            <Text style={styles.text}>{item.title}</Text>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.horizontalLine} />
        </View>
      ))}
    </View>
  );
};
```

On main screen:

```
  const [deleteAll, setDeleteAll] = useState(false);

  const deleteAllFilters = () => {
    setDeleteAll(true);
  };

      <Text style={styles.deleteAllText} onPress={()=>{deleteAllFilters}}>DELETE ALL</Text>
...
 <FilterCriteriaList/>
```

Snack Expo:
https://snack.expo.io/dh3fk53zf

Answer (score 0):

You can pass deleteAll value to your child component and check inside the child component, if deleteAll is true then set checked property of all element of criteriaList array to true.

Comment: I understand that already but if the true value is passed then it will remain true and even if I click on the buttons again, the state will keep getting set to true

Comment: I could not understand your concern, can you please elaborate a little?